# Rg.Plugins.Popup Crashes on closing popup only in UWP

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, popup

I'm using Rg.Plugins.Popup for a while but I can't get it working anymore on UWP for new projects.

While its working perfectly in Android, I get this error in UWP :

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Rg.Plugins.Popup.UWP.dll
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Rg.Plugins.Popup.UWP.dll!Rg.Plugins.Popup.Windows.Renderers.PopupPageRenderer.UpdateElementSize() Line 124
```

I made a small test repo [here](https://github.com/BelightWavre/TestRgPlugIN).
I use Rg.plugins.popup 1.1.5.188, Xamarin 5.0.0.2012 and the targeted plaform in UWP is 10.0.19041.

Can anyone help me and/or check if you get the same behavior ?

I also notice that with Rg.plugins.popup version 2.0.0.12, I get another error :
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Popup' does not exist in the namespace 'Rg.Plugins.Popup' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Here is my initialisation code in UWP, just as describe in the WIKI:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a waste of time ...

https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/issues/527

The ***minimum target*** has to be set to 10.0.17763 or higher. Not only the target version. That was the trick.
So stupid ...